# What python libraries could I use for a time management app?

Tags: python, time-management

I've been working on a time management app, but I've come into some limitations. I'm currently using psutil and win32gui to get processes and track when a window is being used, but I don't think this is ideal.

Psutil allows me to get all currently running processes, but it doesn't provide any way to organize programs by relevancy (An user isn't gonna want to track svchost.exe, and most browsers have multiple processes running at the same time.)

tl;dr: I need a program similar to psutil that gets programs (not processes) from windows and can modify them for my time management app

If this question is in the wrong section or something please let me know! This is the first question of its kind I ask here. Thanks!